# How to remember checkbox preference in user account in html/php site

Tags: php, html, checkbox, phpmyadmin

Good day!

I'm doing a site. There is a checkbox which update the option I choose in phpmyadmin.

But if I press submit, then f5/reload page, the preference I choose disappears on client/html side, (look the image for better understanding)

[Image, open me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM2gv.png)

So basically I want the site remember my choice in the "user account"
I tried with

```
  <form action="pr.php" method="POST">
  <h3 style="color:red;">Numbers?</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a1" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['a1'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  /><label>One</label><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a2" value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['a2'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  /><label>Two</label><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a3" value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['a3'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /><label>3</label><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a4" value="4" <?php if(!is_null($_POST['a4'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /><label>Four</label><br/>

  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

It doesnt work with isset, empty or is_null.

Thanks for all!

Comment: `But if I press f5/reload page`=> it means data is not submitted. that's why data is gone.if you hit submit button and if your action is current page then you will get your data back for sure with your given code.

Comment: While you press f5, If the $_POST data is available in that page you should receive the confirm dialog window, In that window you click the resend button $_POST values will sustain on the same page otherwise it will reset... If you are not get the dialog box there is no $_POST values in your site.. This will happen when you suppose to redirect your site after submit your form

Comment: sorry, fixed, first I press submit, then f5, the values doesnt save in the client side @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 0):

Unless you save the information on a database, even if you clicked on submit, after you refresh the webpage you are going to loose the the values of the variables.

You could use cookies to save the value of the choice that was checked:

```
setcookie("checkbox1","checked");
```

First parameter is `name` of the cookie, second one is the `value` of the cookie, and you can add a third one with the `time` you want the cookie to have before it expires.

And in your if condition, you could do this:

```
<?php if($_COOKIE['a1'] == "checked") echo "checked='checked'"; >
```

For more info, check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).